# Wrap command in the prompt

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt

Is it possible to insert a separator after the command in a prompt? This is an example:

```
~/Desktop: ls -al
-------------------------------------
total 80
drwx------+  6 eddie  staff   204B Apr 29 16:57 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 54 eddie  staff   1.8K Apr 30 10:54 ..

~/Desktop:
```

Specifically I want to add the --------- part after issuing a command to easier distinguish the command from the result

Comment: For every command? What shell?

Comment: Ideally for every command that actually has an output. zsh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In zsh, you can define the hook function [`preexec`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html) to echo a specified string before every command is executed.

In bash, you could use the `DEBUG` trap to set up a preexec hook to do the same.

You would define a preexec() function something like this:

```
preexec () { echo "-------------------------------"; }
preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    preexec
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

See more details at [Does bash have a hook that is run before executing a command?](https://superuser.com/a/175802/75777)

I don't think this works in all versions of bash though. On my old Ubuntu server, running bash 3.2.39(1), `help trap` says

> If a SIGNAL_SPEC is DEBUG, ARG is executed **after** every simple
>   command.

On another server, running bash 4.1.2(1), it says

> If a SIGNAL_SPEC is DEBUG, ARG is executed **before** every simple command.

which is what we need.
So make sure that in your version of bash, `help trap` says "**before** every simple command."

Answer (score 5):

If you're using bash or ksh for your shell, you can create a function in one of your dotfiles (.profile, .bash_profile, etc) like so:

```
function hr {
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

Then, you can prepend it to commands whenever you want that separator using `&&` or `;` as command separators. As in:

```
bash-[534]$ hr && ls
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ddtool_23.jnlp  prtconf-pv
```

or

```
bash-[536]$ hr ; ls -la
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
total 36K
drwxr-xr-x  2 tim staff    4 2012-12-06 15:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 46 tim staff  134 2013-04-30 14:59 ../
-rw-------  1 tim staff 2.7K 2012-12-06 15:00 ddtool_23.jnlp
-rw-r--r--  1 tim staff  24K 2012-12-06 15:02 prtconf-pv
```

I do this.  I have a second function that prints a thicker separator, as well.

```
function hr2 {
    echo "================================================================================"
}
```

I often use these functions in shell scripts to provide separation to different parts of the scripts, such as `hr2` between main tasks, and `hr` between items in a loop statement.  It makes reading script output much easier.

Comment: Why not `function hr { echo '---…'; "$@"; }` instead? Then you can use it without `&&` or `;` too: `hr ls -la`. By the way, an even thicker separator: `figlet -- '---…'`.

Comment: mostly because i never thought of that. thanks for the idea. :)